# Using .translate() on a string to strip digits [Python 3]

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Let's say I have the string '2okjser823ab'. How can I remove all the numbers from the string using .translate()?

I see that in Python 2.x you can do something like .translate(None, '0123456789') but if I try this in Python 3 it tells me that the method only takes one argument.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's a bit harder in Python 3; not sure why.

Here's what you can do:

```
>>> import string
>>> translation = str.maketrans(string.ascii_letters, string.ascii_letters, string.digits)
>>> "2okjser823ab".translate(translation)
'okjserab'
```

You may need to expand `string.ascii_letters` with whatever else you expect as input (`string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.whitespace`, for example).

Edit: I can't find it clearly in the documentation for `str.maketrans`, but if you use an empty string for the first two arguments, everything will be mapped 1 to 1, but the deletion part (the third argument) still happens:

```
>>> translation = str.maketrans("", "", string.digits)
>>> "2eeŷýéeokjser823 ab.;\t".translate(translation)
'eeŷýéeokjser ab.;\t'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for [maketrans in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html), and for [string functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).

In `maketrans(x, y, z)`, each character in x is mapped to the character at the same position in y - setting up a substitution of x for y. Characters in z are mapped to `None`. Consequently, they will be removed.

Adding to user707650's answer, here is a more compact implementation, where we pass empty strings `''` as the first two arguments. Passing `string.digits` as the third argument strips away digits 0-9.

```
import string
line = '@ qu1ck br0wn f0x jump3 0ver the l@zy d0g'
line = line.translate(line.maketrans('', '', string.digits))
print(line)
# Result: @ quck brwn fx jump ver the l@zy dg
```

If you would also like to remove punctuation, then you can add

```
line = line.translate(line.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
# Result:  quck brwn fx jump ver the lzy dg
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use the `strip` function :

```
strings="tycoon0123456789999"
strings.strip("0123456789")
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: Please read the question. [`strip()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) does only remove characters from both ends of a string, not in the middle as requested by the OP.